# Fetching data from API into states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have the following in **App.js**

```
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {data: 'false'};
  }



  componentDidMount(){
      this._getData();
  }



  _getData = () => {
      const url = 'http://localhost:8888/chats';

      fetch(url, { credentials: 'include' })
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(json => this.setState({ data: json.chats }))

  }

  render() {
      return (
           <div className="App">
              {
               this.state.chats &&
               this.state.chats.map( (buddy, key) =>
                  <div key={key}>
                    {buddy}
                  </div>
               )}
               <Chat />
           </div>
      )
  }
```

and I have this in **Chat.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Chat extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div className="App">
                MY Chat
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Chat;
```

and I have this in my **http://localhost:8888/chats**

```
{"chats":[{"buddy":"x","lastMessage":"Hey how are you?","timestamp":"2017-12-01T14:00:00.000Z"},{"buddy":"y","lastMessage":"I agree, react will take over the world one day.","timestamp":"2017-12-03T01:10:00.000Z"}]}
```

But I am getting empty arrays and a waring as follows:

> The connection to
>   ws://localhost:3000/sockjs-node/321/uglf2ovt/websocket was interrupted
>   while the page was loading.

```
Object {  }
mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
Object {  }
```

I am not sure what is wrong, why are the variables empty ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your state has a property called `data` and when `fetch` returns you save on that `data` property. BUT on `render()` you use `this.state.chats` instead of `this.state.data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the problem when not getting any data, bind your method in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { chats: 'false'};
    this._getData = this._getData.bind(this);
}
```

Also you are not passing any props to the Chat component. For example you can do:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
           {
            this.state.chats &&
            this.state.chats.map( (buddy, key) =>
                <div key={key}>
                    {buddy}
                </div>
            )}
            <Chat chats={this.state.chats} />
        </div>
     );
}
```

So when you are doing the console.log

```
class Chat extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props); // Here you will have an object like { chats: [data] }
    return (
      <div className="App">
      MY Chat
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: Unifying the state attributes, you should change it in the method like:

```
_getData = () => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8888/chats';

    fetch(url, { credentials: 'include' })
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(json => this.setState({ chats: json.chats }))

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this solved the problem. But I am getting a new one. I get this in the console `Object { chats: undefined }`. Any ideas why might that is happening ?

Comment: Because you are saving the fetch data in an attribute called data in state, and then trying to print an attribute from state called chats. I will rewrite my answer for that.

Comment: Thanks so much, you saved me hours of research

Comment: I know you already anwered the question but I will really really appreciate it if you tell me how to sort this problem out as u already have gone through the code. After the change I am getting this `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {buddy, lastMessage, timestamp}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. in div (at App.js:38) in div (at App.js:34) in App (at index.js:6)`. Do I need more keys ? if so how ? Thanks again. And if you don't want to asnwer it is understandable :)

Comment: Do a console.log before doing the map of this.state.chats and check if you are trying to loop an array.

Comment: It is pointing at this line `.then(json => this.setState({ chats: json.chats }))`

Comment: something like this `console.log(this.props);` before the `this.state.chats && ....` ?

Comment: `console.log(this.state);` before that line you are saying. You want to know what are you saving in your state and then looping and find out about that error.